# cardservice and additem for dropdown list: how to add an array?

Tags: google-apps-script, dropdown, google-workspace-add-ons

I would like to add an array of elements in cardservice section "additem". I'm not familiar with cardservice.

```
   function myFunction() {
var action = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('notificationCallback');
var pratiche =["ciaone","ciao","ciao2","ciao3"]


return CardService
     .newCardBuilder()
     .setHeader(
         CardService.newCardHeader()
             .setTitle('Elenco operazioni rapide')
             .setSubtitle('Inserisci rapidamente gli eventi con questi tasti'))

     .addSection(
          CardService.newCardSection()
              .addWidget(CardService.newSelectionInput().setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.DROPDOWN)
              .setTitle("A group of checkboxes. Multiple selections are allowed.")
                 .setFieldName("CLIENTI")
                 .addItem(pratiche, "checkbox_one_value", false)


                 .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('notificationCallback')))
                 .addWidget(CardService.newSelectionInput().setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.DROPDOWN)
              .setTitle("A group of checkboxes. Multiple selections are allowed.")
                 .setFieldName("PRATICHE")
                 .addItem("Elenco clienti2", "checkbox_two_value", false)
              .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('inseriscievento')))
              .addWidget(CardService.newTextButton().setText('Telefonata').setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED).setOnClickAction(action))
              .addWidget(CardService.newTextButton().setText('Incontro').setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED).setOnClickAction(action)))



     .build();
     }
```

Peraphs it is easy, but...not runs. I've tried also pratiche[]...not runs...I also thought to insert a for cycle for additem, but it's not run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to add each dropdown option as a separate `item`
- If you want to use checkboxes instead of a dropdown - please use `CardService.SelectionInputType.CHECK_BOX`

  instead of

  `CardService.SelectionInputType.DROPDOWN`

### Sample

```
function myFunction() {
  var action = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('notificationCallback');
  var pratiche =["ciaone","ciao","ciao2","ciao3"]


  return CardService
  .newCardBuilder()
  .setHeader(
    CardService.newCardHeader()
    .setTitle('Elenco operazioni rapide')
    .setSubtitle('Inserisci rapidamente gli eventi con questi tasti'))  
  .addSection(
    CardService.newCardSection()
    .addWidget(CardService.newSelectionInput().setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.CHECK_BOX)
               .setTitle("A group of checkboxes. Multiple selections are allowed.")
               .setFieldName("CLIENTI")
               .addItem(pratiche[0], "checkbox_one_value", false)
               .addItem(pratiche[1], "checkbox_one_value", false)
               .addItem(pratiche[2], "checkbox_one_value", false)
               .addItem(pratiche[3], "checkbox_one_value", false)               
               .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('notificationCallback')))
    .addWidget(CardService.newSelectionInput().setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.DROPDOWN)
               .setTitle("A group of checkboxes. Multiple selections are allowed.")
               .setFieldName("PRATICHE")
               .addItem("Elenco clienti2", "checkbox_two_value", false)
               .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('inseriscievento')))
    .addWidget(CardService.newTextButton().setText('Telefonata').setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED).setOnClickAction(action))
    .addWidget(CardService.newTextButton().setText('Incontro').setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED).setOnClickAction(action)))  
  .build();
}
```

You can also do it with a loop:

```
  var widget = CardService.newSelectionInput()  
  widget.setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.CHECK_BOX)
  .setTitle("A group of checkboxes. Multiple selections are allowed.")
  .setFieldName("CLIENTI")
  .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('notificationCallback'))
  for(var i = 0; i < pratiche.length; i++){
    widget.addItem(pratiche[i], "checkbox_one_value", false)
  }             

  return CardService
  .newCardBuilder()
  .setHeader(
    CardService.newCardHeader()
    .setTitle('Elenco operazioni rapide')
    .setSubtitle('Inserisci rapidamente gli eventi con questi tasti'))  
  .addSection(
    CardService.newCardSection()
    .addWidget(widget)
     ...   
  ).build();
```

Comment: Mmm...ok for this solution, but I would like to use a cycle for...I Need to load a lot of data...or charge all Array in One step.

Comment: I just updated my answer to show how you can do it for a larger data amount with a loop. The crucial thing is that you need to call `addItem` for every array entry.